# Campo primary key de int para bigint

Tags: mysql, sql

Bom estou precisando transformar meus campos primarykay de int para bigint, porem está dando um problema. Segue o código abaixo:

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1025: Error on rename of './DB_ATOS542/#sql-b4b_210' to './DB_ATOS542/tbl_PESSOAS' (errno: 150)
SQL Code:
        ALTER TABLE `DB_ATOS542`.`tbl_PESSOAS` 
        CHANGE COLUMN `COD_IDENT_PESSO` `COD_IDENT_PESSO` BIGINT NOT NULL 

SQL script execution finished: statements: 3 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

Comment: essa tabela tem referencia em outras tabelas?
pois toda FK que aponte para esse campo vc tera que tirar as constrains para poder alterar.

Comment: Qual é a atitude correta a se faze ?

Comment: você precisa MESMO passar para bigint? tudo depende da profundidade dos dados, se tiver mtas tabelas referenciada é mais complicado, se nao tiver, cria uma coluna nova bigint e exclui a antiga. tudo depende do caso. de mais informacoes.

Comment: Realmente minha tabela está ligada em varias outras, porem estou fazendo tudo pelo workbench

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema aí é que você está tentando alterar o tipo de um campo primary key que possui foreign keys que referenciam ele, isso não é permitido pois um campo foreign key sempre tem que ter o mesmo tipo do campo ao qual ele referência, exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE bla(id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT);
```

nesse caso você pode alterar o tipo do campo id para BIGINT sem problemas, mesmo possuindo dados. Agora digamos que que adicionei uma table que possui uma foreign key que referência esse meu campo id de "bla"

```
CREATE TABLE bla2(id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, fk_bla INT, FOREIGN KEY (fk_bla) REFERENCES bla(id));
```

e depois a tentativa de converter o campo id para BIGINT

```
ALTER TABLE bla MODIFY id BIGINT;
ERROR 1025 (HY000): Error on rename of './test/#sql-47c_2' to './test/bla' (errno: 150)
```

Como escrevi acima, isso não é permitido pois ambas, PK e FK que referência a PK precisam manter o mesmo tipo. Para permitir essa alteração o que você deve fazer é:

1) remover as FK constraints que referenciam a coluna que você deseja alterar

2) realizar a alteração de tipo na coluna desejada **e também nas colunas FK** (cuja constraint você removeu temporariamente)

3) recriar as constraints FOREIGN KEY

seguindo o exemplo

```
-- removendo a FK que referência bla.id
ALTER TABLE bla2 DROP FOREIGN KEY bla2_ibfk_1; 
-- "bla2_ibfk_1" é o nome da FK constraint, nesse caso é algo gerado automaticamente pelo mysql

-- alterando os tipos de INT para BIGINT
ALTER TABLE bla MODIFY id BIGINT;
ALTER TABLE bla2 MODIFY fk_bla BIGINT;

-- finalmente recriando a FK constraint
ALTER TABLE bla2 ADD CONSTRAINT bla2_fk_bla FOREIGN KEY fk_bla (fk_bla) REFERENCES bla(id);
```

Como você pode ver o processo é um pouco trabalhoso ;)